# Implementation a Keras model in XCUBE AI

Tags: stm32, tf.keras

when I try to analyze my model with XCUBE AI tool i get this error : INTERNAL ERROR: Unconsistent data. Filter size [3, 3], strides (1, 1), in_shape(7, 8, 8)

my input shape is (B, H , W, C ).
how can I fix this error ?
#XCUBE_AI

I try to analyze my model by uploading .H5 file to XCUBE AI tool.